# R aggregate data.frame having dates and hours in one column misformatted

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, aggregate, ggplotly

I have a data frame like the following:

```
   kWh   Equipment                date
1 1.53 aquecedor01 2015-01-01 00:00:00
2 5.29 aquecedor01 2015-01-01 01:00:00
3 5.73 aquecedor01 2015-01-01 02:00:00
```

but when I aggregate data by the Equipment variable to find the maximum value from kWh, the date column is misformatted to something like this:

```
     Equipment kWh       date
1  aquecedor01 6.5 1433023200
2  aquecedor02 6.5 1433023200
3     exaustor 6.5 1433023200
```

I have been struggling with this for a while now and the most things I find around only works with dates or hours independently. In my case, since I am performing a plot in Shiny app it would be easier for me to do all at once.

I would like to plot in a bar plot all maximum values for each equipment and write on the bar which was the time for that value. This is my code to do that:

```
ggplotly(ggplot(data=aggregate(
        . ~ Equipment,
        data = dt.hourly[(as.character(input$dateRange[1]) <= dt.hourly$date) & 
                           (as.character(input$dateRange[2]) > dt.hourly$date) &
                           (dt.hourly$Equipment %in% input$equipments),], max),
        aes(x=Equipment, y=kWh)) +
        geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') +
        geom_text(aes(label=date),
                  position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
                  angle = 90,
                  size=2) +
        xlab("Date") + 
        ylab("Consumption (kWh)") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))
    ))
```

Apart from that `angle=90` is being ignored and I can't figure out why.
This is what I am getting:

[image: ggplot]

Thks in advance.

As a reproducible example:

```
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
dt <- data.frame(
  kWh = sample(10:100, 10, replace = TRUE)/100,
  Equipment = sample(c("heater", "furnace", "AC"), 10, replace = TRUE),
  date = sample(as.POSIXct(c("2015-01-14 17:00:00", "2015-01-21 20:00:00", "2015-01-21 22:00:00", "2015-02-21 20:00:00", "2015-01-22 14:00:00", "2015-02-14 17:00:00", "2015-02-21 20:00:00", "2015-02-21 22:00:00", "2015-03-21 20:00:00", "2015-03-22 14:00:00" )), 10, replace = TRUE)
)
```

And for ploting:

```
ggplotly(ggplot(data=aggregate(
  . ~ Equipment,
  data = dt[("2015-01-12" <= dt$date) & 
              ("2015-02-22" > dt$date) &
              (dt$Equipment %in% c("AC", "furnace")),], max),
  aes(x=Equipment, y=kWh)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=date),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            angle = 90,
            size=2) +
  xlab("Date") + 
  ylab("Consumption (kWh)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)))
```

and the `dput` output is:

```
structure(list(kWh = c(0.34, 0.43, 0.62, 0.92, 0.28, 0.91, 0.95, 
0.7, 0.67, 0.15), Equipment = structure(c(3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("AC", "furnace", "heater"), class = "factor"), 
    date = structure(c(1427032800, 1421877600, 1424548800, 1421870400, 
    1421877600, 1424548800, 1421254800, 1424548800, 1426968000, 
    1424548800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example? What is `input` and is the data.frame you provide `dt.hourly`? Also use `dput` to share the structure of your data and make it easier to copy and paste your example. See also [How to make a great reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: @kath `input` is the shiny app variable for information controlled by the user. `dt.hourly` is my data frame (like `dt` in the reproducible example).

Comment: I see, thanks for the example! One additional question: With the aggregate call do you really want to have the maximum kWh and the maximum date or do you want to have the maximum kWh with the corresponding date?

Comment: @kath, Is the second one. I would like to get the date and hour at which occur the greater kWh value in each equipment. Thks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the data according to you need before you plot it:

```
library(tidyverse) 

dt_sum <- dt %>% 
  # First filter according to your input 
  filter(Equipment %in% c("AC", "furnace") & ("2015-01-12" <= date) & ("2015-02-22" > date)) %>%  
  group_by(Equipment) %>%   #  Group the data by Equipment
  top_n(1, kWh) %>%   # Take the maximum kWh value per Equipment
  top_n(1, date)      # Take the maximum date if there are several with the same max kWh value

dt_sum
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Equipment [2]
#     kWh Equipment date               
#   <dbl> <fct>     <dttm>             
# 1  0.92 furnace   2015-01-21 20:00:00
# 2  0.95 AC        2015-01-14 17:00:00

p <- ggplot(dt_sum, aes(x = Equipment, y = kWh)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat = 'identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label = date), position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            angle = 90, size = 2) +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Consumption (kWh)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1))

p
```

[image]

The angle-problem is due to `ggplotly` (as you can see the `angle = 90` is not ignored in the `ggplot`-call).

```
ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since your objective is to annotate the date when the max *kWh* occurred, you want to leave out *date* in the aggregation. Therefore, consider calculating grouped *max_kWh* with `ave` which adds a same length column (inline aggregation). Then subset your data frame where `kWh == max_kWh`.

```
dt$max_kWh <- with(dt, ave(kWh, Equipment, FUN=max))

agg_dt <- subset(dt, kWh == max_kWh)

ggplot(data=agg_dt, aes(x=Equipment, y=kWh)) +
  geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') +
  geom_text(aes(label=date),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
            angle = 0,
            size = 2) +
  xlab("Equipment") + 
  ylab("Consumption (kWh)") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1))
```

[image: Plot Output]

---

For your Shiny integration that reads *input* values, use `transform` to add *max_kWh* column and then wrap result in `subset`:

```
agg_dt <- subset(
             transform(dt.hourly[(as.character(input$dateRange[1]) <= dt.hourly$date) & 
                                 (as.character(input$dateRange[2]) > dt.hourly$date) &
                                 (dt.hourly$Equipment %in% input$equipments),],
                       max_kWh = ave(kWh, Equipment, FUN=max),
             kWh == max_kWh
          )

ggplotly(ggplot(data=agg_dt, aes(x=Equipment, y=kWh)) +
            geom_bar(position = 'dodge', stat='identity') +
            geom_text(aes(label=date),
                      position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5),
                      angle = 0,
                      size = 2) +
            xlab("Date") + 
            ylab("Consumption (kWh)") +
        theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 1))
))
```